# how to make a scrollable legend in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, bokeh

I make `bokeh` line plots from `pandas DataFrames` with many columns. I have already managed to hide individual lines by clicking on the corresponding legend entry. However, the legend is too big and does not fit in the graph. I have tried placing the legend outside of the graph, still does not work.

Is there a way to make the legend of a `bokeh` plot scrollable?

I know, I could increase the size of the whole figure, but than it does not fit on my screen. And I also don't want to make the font of the legend entries smaller.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Category20_20

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {str(key): [
    np.random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(100)
    ]
    for key in range(20)
}

data1=pd.DataFrame(data1)


data2 = {str(key): [
    np.random.randint(5, 15) for i in range(100)
    ]
    for key in range(20)
}

data2=pd.DataFrame(data2)


graph1 = figure(
    title='Top graph'
)
graph2 = figure(
    title='Bottom Graph',
    x_range=graph1.x_range,
)
for col, color in zip(data1.columns, Category20_20):
    graph1.line(
        data1.index,
        data1[col],
        legend_label=col,
        color=color,
    )

for col, color in zip(data2.columns, Category20_20):
    graph2.line(
        data2.index,
        data2[col],
        legend_label=col,
        color=color,
    )

overplot = gridplot(
    [[graph1, None], [graph2, None]],
    width=1000,
    height=400,
)

graph1.add_layout(graph1.legend[0], 'right')

graph1.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
graph2.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

show(overplot)
```

Comment: As fas as I know this is not possible. But the legend object is under active development right now, see [issue 12701](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/12701). Maybe it is a good moment to open a [feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

Comment: Since the release of bokeh 3.1 (march '23) the option of grided tabulare exists.